# Signal doesn't show all of the noise I've inputted

Tags: arduino-ide, waveform

I've set up a simple code so that I can generate a noisy sine wave, however when I look in the serial plotter the signal seems too smooth, and the only times I've seen any noise are when the frequencies are extremely low. I'm using the function S = 5sin(2pi*f1*t)+.25(2pi*f2*t)+.15sin(2pi*f3*t)

Ideally, I'd like a signal that is fairly noisy, as I'll be sending it through a low pass filter with a cutoff frequency of around 200 Hz.

I set up the code based on three separate sine waves. I expected that when I combined them to see a large wavefunction with three levels of noise, however I've only ever seen 2 levels of noise, and that's if the frequency is very low. I've never seen a third layer of noise, which would be the frequency I'm trying to filter out.